# get data from to tables !

Tags: sql, mysql

i have user list , and i have select box to filter userlist one of the select box options is show by most viewed so i have also need user information too .
i want to sort my users based on most viewed profile in my user list .
i have these two tables but i don't know how to right correct query to make this happen .
i used grouping like this :

```
$sql ="select userid , count(*) form profile_visit group by userid " ;
```

but it's not make sense to me , i don't think this query will help me at all .

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| userid    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |

| username  | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| password  | char(40)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| email     | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| name      | varchar(256)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| lastname  | varchar(256)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| job       | varchar(256)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| birthdate | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| address   | varchar(1024) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| website   | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| tel       | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |

| role      | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 0                 |                |

| reg_date  | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |

+-----------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

and profile_visit table like this

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ip_address | varchar(70) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userid     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Your query seems fine to me. What problem are your experiencing?

Comment: i have user list , and i have select box to filter userlist one of the select box options is show by most viewed so i have also need user information too .

Comment: actually i have to query user table where max visit num or a range of visit nums .

Comment: You might want to update the question with the additional detail given in your comments above, as it seems to change the question significantly. Maybe you could throw in a made up example of the expected output data?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT userid , COUNT(*) AS visits FROM profile_visit GROUP BY userid ORDER BY visits DESC" ;
```

That should group as you were expecting, but order the results in descending order based on the number of visits they have had.

I would ask whether it is necessary to have a separate table? Do you need details of all the visits to be stored, or could you just increment a "visits" integer for each user?

Comment: if i do that how can i be sure that this visitor already check my user profile or not . i think it's can be done by holding visitor ip addresses in separate table

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you wanted to see visits for specific visitors.

Still, my query above should do what you want on the separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the typo in <del>`form`</del> `from` your query looks reasonable. It should give you the profile identifiers and their view counts.

As I understand your question, you simply need to get the data out sorted in descending order, which is achievable by simply appending an `order by` to your query (using an alias for the aggregated column makes it an easier read):

```
select userid , count(*) as visitcount
from profile_visit
group by userid
order by visitcount
```